# Trying to find out more about this John Exshaw bottle

Tags: cognac

I just found two bottles of Exshaw. The reason I bought them was because someone close to me used to drink this (years ago).

I got a pretty good bargain on them so just went with it. When I opened them to my surprise the cork is actually a plastic one rather than actual cork. I wanted to see if anyone here has more history on this brand as well as information on what type of cognac it would, when it would have been distilled and bottled (Exshaw is long gone).

[image]

The bottle seemed to have been imported by the Borneo company into Malaysia.